# cloudformation template for watch rule for batch job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to create a cloudformation template for the cron rule as set in the following screenshot?

[image]

I tried to search for an example that I can use. But I could not find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic template would be (all the ARNs must be changed to yours) with [AWS::Events::Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-events-rule.html):

```
Resources:

  MyCWEventRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties: 
      Name: my-batch-event-rule
      ScheduleExpression: cron(01 04 ? * * *)
      State: ENABLED
      Targets: 
        - Id: my-batch-job
          Arn: arn:aws:batch:us-east-1:xxxxx:job-queue/first-run-job-queue # <job-queue-arn>
          BatchParameters: 
            JobDefinition: arn:aws:batch:us-east-1:xxxx:job-definition/td-job:1
            JobName: tds-job
          RoleArn: arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/service-role/AWS_Events_Invoke_Batch_Job_Queue_1226795150
```